# How to fix up and down controls/spins of input type date after changing its height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have this code where I changed the height of my inputs (date type) to 40px, and now the up and down controls are not aligned to the text inside the field.

I want to adjust the height of the spins or just remove it if fixing it won't be possible.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>From <input type="date" name="from" value="'.$currdate.'" autofocus/> </td>
        <td>To  <input type="date" name="to" value="'.$currdate.'" />  </td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I don't know if this can be done through jQuery or javascript.

Comment: Please apply basic grammar to your question. That is: A sentence starts with a capital letter and ends with a full stop.

Comment: Spelling and grammar fix.

Comment: Thanks for the fix :) and sorry for the wrong grammar. I'm a bit in a hurry at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
input, ::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>From <input type="date" name="from" value="" autofocus/> </td>
        <td>To  <input type="date" name="to" value="" /> </td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is this what you're looking for?

The following 8 pseudo-elements are made available by WebKit for customizing a date input’s textbox:

> ::-webkit-datetime-edit ::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper
>   ::-webkit-datetime-edit-text ::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field
>   ::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field ::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field
>   ::-webkit-inner-spin-button ::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator

Comment: Wow! I thought you would recommend using javascript/jquery (which I am not yet very familiar with,-insert deep breathe here-) Btw, thanks :)